# How to terminate a while loop

Tags: iteration

I'm not very skilled in elisp, I have only a minimal knowledge of it.

I have to modify an existing function, as I'm trying to fix a problem in an obsolete emacs  package that could fulfill my needs.?

```lisp
(defun okk-tmpl-insert (template)
  "Insert template into buffer, performing tag expansions.
See `okk-tmpl-tag-alist' for list of predefined tags."
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "Template file to insert: " okk-tmpl-dir nil t)))
  (setq okk-tmpl-prompt-start-point nil)
  (setq okk-tmpl-prompted-strings '())
  (setq okk-tmpl-eval-start-point nil)
  (setq okk-tmpl-final-point nil)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (point) (point))
    (insert-file-contents template)
    (let (char result)
      (while (search-forward "%" nil t)
        (delete-char -1)
        (setq char (char-after))
        (delete-char 1)
        (setq result (assoc (char-to-string char) okk-tmpl-tag-alist))
        (if (not result)
            (error "Unknown tag %%%c" char)
          (setq result (eval (cdr result)))
          (when (stringp result) (insert result))))
      (when okk-tmpl-final-point (goto-char okk-tmpl-final-point)))
    (run-hooks 'okk-tmpl-insert-hook)))
```

I have modified the parser to set a variable when it is finding a "tag". Now I have to terminate the  loop: `(while (search-forward "%" nil t)`.

when this variable is `t` to terminate the template expansion, that will occur mainly on the start of the code snippets (a real file template in reality).

The code is derived from `file-template.el`, from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/file-template.el but stripped to do a bare minimun work without any automation, I fire the template insertion, select a template and then manually save the modified file.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To terminate the loop when a variable is `t`, change the condition to

```
  (while (and (search-forward "%" nil t) (not variable))
```

Comment: Many Thanks it works as expected.

For now it suffice to fulfill my needs, but I have another idea in mind, it is possible to "skip" the tag expansion using same variable until a different tag is found?

As example **%Z0** will 'suspend' expansion and **%Z1** will reactivate expansion.

But as it is not related to the original question, I could made another question if required by forum rules (If this could be considered a 'forum').

Comment: Creating a new question is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: Also, "Many Thanks" = Accept ;-)

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what the previous comment means :-)